# Altering a variable within a .tflite model in Xcode?

Tags: python, swift, xcode, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to implement the Neural Style Transfer model by https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.07629.pdf in an iOS app. The paper uses this conditional instance norm layer to allow a single model to learn multiple styles and also combine the styles.

Here is my code for it:

```
class ConditionalInstanceNorm(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, scope_bn, y1, y2, alpha):
    super(ConditionalInstanceNorm, self).__init__()
    self.scope_bn = scope_bn
    self.y1 = y1
    self.y2 = y2
    self.alpha = alpha
  
  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.beta = self.add_weight(name="beta"+self.scope_bn, shape=(self.y1.shape[-1], input_shape[-1]), initializer=betaInitializer, trainable=True)
    self.gamma = self.add_weight(name="gamma"+self.scope_bn, shape=(self.y1.shape[-1], input_shape[-1]), initializer=gammaInitializer, trainable=True)
  
  def call(self, inputs):
    mean, var = tf.nn.moments(x=inputs, axes=[1,2], keepdims=True)
    beta1 = tf.matmul(self.y1, self.beta)
    gamma1 = tf.matmul(self.y1, self.gamma)
    beta2 = tf.matmul(self.y2, self.beta)
    gamma2 = tf.matmul(self.y2, self.gamma)
    beta = self.alpha*beta1 + (1. - self.alpha)*beta2
    gamma = self.alpha*gamma1 + (1. - self.alpha)*gamma2
    x = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x=inputs, mean=mean, variance=var, offset=beta, scale=gamma, variance_epsilon=1e-10)
    return x
```

It requires me to pass in 3 hyper-parameters: y1, y2, and alpha. Each style has a unique y value (y1 and y2 are the different styles to allow combining of styles). Alpha determines the strength of influence of each style.

In python, the way I switch between different combinations of styles is by accessing each layer, identify the conditional instance norm layers then change the y1, y2, and alpha values stored:

```
  for layer in filter(lambda x: "conditional_instance_norm" in x.name, model.layers):
    layer.y1 = y1
    layer.y1 = y2
    layer.alpha = alpha
```

How can I do this with a .tflite model in swift? Right now I can run the model but it is stuck with the y1, y2, and alpha values it was initialised with.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of being able to input the values by altering the structure of my model in python to include 3 additional inputs - y1, y2, and alpha, like this:

```
def ImageTransformNetwork():
  inputs = Input(shape=(dim,dim,3))
  y1 = Input(shape=(13), batch_size=1)
  y2 = Input(shape=(13), batch_size=1)
  alpha = Input(shape=(1), batch_size=1)
  x = PadConvBatch(x=inputs, kernel_size=9, scope_bn="1", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha) 
  x = PadConvBatch(x=x, filters=64, strides=2, scope_bn="2", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
  x = PadConvBatch(x=x, filters=128, strides=2, scope_bn="3", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
  x = Resblock(x=x, scope_bn1="4", scope_bn2="5", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
  x = Resblock(x=x, scope_bn1="6", scope_bn2="7", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
  x = Resblock(x=x, scope_bn1="8", scope_bn2="9", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
  x = Resblock(x=x, scope_bn1="10", scope_bn2="11", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
  x = Resblock(x=x, scope_bn1="12", scope_bn2="13", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
  x = PadConvBatch(x=x, filters=64, strides=0.5, scope_bn="14", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
  x = PadConvBatch(x=x, filters=32, strides=0.5, scope_bn="15", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
  x = tf.pad(x, [[0,0], [4,4], [4,4], [0,0]], "REFLECT")
  x = Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=9, strides=1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=initializer)(x)
  model = Model(inputs=[inputs, y1, y2, alpha], outputs=x)
  return model
```

Thus after converting this to a tflite model, I can put in my variables like such:

```
try self.imageTransformInterpreter.copy(inputRGBData, toInputAt: 3)
try self.imageTransformInterpreter.copy(Data(bytes: yArray1, count: 52), toInputAt: 0)
try self.imageTransformInterpreter.copy(Data(bytes: yArray2, count: 52), toInputAt: 2)
try self.imageTransformInterpreter.copy(Data(buffer: alphaBuffer), toInputAt: 1)
```

Comment: However I've now encountered a different problem, I'm unable to find a way of converting an array: [[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] into data that can fit into the model. y1 and y2 are arrays like this. I'm not sure if the current method above Data(bytes:, count:) works as yArray1 = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] as is yArray2

Comment: I fixed this issue, I realised why I was getting a mismatch between the byte count of the input and the required byte count - it's because I was setting my data in the Int format when the input for the model has defaulted to the float32 format, so I just needed to convert my y1 and y2 arrays into float32 format and it worked.